# toggle анимация при клике

Tags: javascript

как сделать анимацию `fadeIn` `fadeOut` как в jQuery только без jQuery. Пробовал так но не вышло

```js
document.querySelector(".toggle").onclick = function() {
  let d = document.querySelector(".box")
  d.classList.toggle("unbox")
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: #abc;
  display: none;
  animation: drop 1s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.unbox {
  background-color: #abc;
  width: 200px;
  animation: undrop 1s;
  height: 200px;
}

@keyframes drop {
  from {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes undrop {
  from {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Вопрос решено так: codepen.io/matdoidge/pen/YPNNea

Comment: @MaximLensky мне нужно чтобы при исчезновении стал display none, чтобы не заняло мест

Comment: тогда появляется без плавного transition, у меня работает в этом случае transition как delay

Comment: так вроде : https://codepen.io/matdoidge/pen/YPNNea

Comment: @MaximLensky В комментариях я не могу принять ответ (зеленая птичка), пишите под вопросом

Comment: да вопрос решено)